# SFML and VS2013 - WinMain/main linker error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker, linker-errors, sfml

I am trying to use SFML with Visual Studio 2013 using the tutorial on the SFML [website](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/start-vc.php) and using their sample code (replacing main() with WinMain()) but I'm getting the linker error:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function _WinMain@16

I am referencing the libs:

- sfml-graphics-d.lib
- sfml-window-d.lib
- sfml-main-d.lib
- sfml-system-d.lib

and I am pointing correctly to the 'include' and 'lib' folders in my Project Properties.

I have tried using 'main()' with sfml-main-d.lib referenced and 'WinMain()' without it referenced and I still get the linker error.

Any suggestions?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Did you download the right pre-compiled package?

Comment: I think so, I tried using the 64-bit version and changing to x64 in the Configuration Manager of the Project Properties but still had this error. Then I realised I wanted to create a x86 project anyway so I can run the project on some older machines I have. So I downloaded the 32-bit version and created a new project from scratch, and this is where I currently am.

Comment: And I've also made sure I've got the VS2013 version (not 2012 or 2010 etc.) if that's what you meant.

Answer (score -1):

Okay I seem to have solved it but don't know how. I'll do my best to explain to anyone else who is stuck:

I started a new project again with a fresh download of SFML 32-bit for VS2013.

I added sfml-main-d.lib and sfml-main.lib to my referenced libs (for debug and release respectively) and then use "int main()..." instead of "int __stdcall WinMain()" and it linked and compiled correctly.

I thought I had already tried this combination but I guess maybe not.

Thanks to anyone who took the time to read this question and to Elried for commenting.